# su postgres: Sorry?

Tags: database, postgresql, console, su

i have a problem with my postgreSQL setup on my new Mac OSX Lion machine.

I can't seem to connect to the service

```
$ createuser -a -d _postgres
Password: 
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
```

I have no chance to find the correct password. Any idea what could that be. I have the default setup with a localhost server. The same happens when I try to connect via pgAdmin.

```
$ su postgres
Password:
su: Sorry
```

I have no chance to find out what's wrong?

Comment: Is `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user` the reason?

Comment: no, id don't think so. I typed my userpass a 100 times. It's always the same message. And I don't think in this case I should enter the userpass, but rather the database password!

Comment: It's just silly to suggest that this isn't on topic.

Comment: I posted the equivalent of this Question on the DBA Stack Exchange: [*Switch user to 'postgres' user on macOS results in “su: Sorry” error*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221043/19079)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

try this:

```
$ sudo su postgres
```

And specify your own password.

Comment: this does work! `bash-3.2$ ` However how can I fix the problem with `createuser -a -d _postgres` -> `could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Usually when you are logged in as postgres, you have superuser access to the database and doesn't need to provide the password for the postgres user.

Comment: I came from running this tutorial: https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/6800
where a postgres is installed and one is asked to login "su - postgres" which asked for a password which in fact does not exist. So sudoing helped: "sudo su - postgres"

Comment: Thanks so much for this huge tip! [I posted the same info](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/221044/19079) on DBA Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 12):

Does this work?

First get root access

```
$ su - 
Password: RootPW
# su - postgres
```