# Can't log into system user postgres

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I installed postgresql on mac using brew. I wasn't asked about for the password for postgresql during the installation. Now I need to create a user and can't:

```
Alexs-MacBook-Air:mydir alex$ su - postgres
Password:
su: Sorry
```

Whatever password (including empty) I use, it is wrong. What's the easiest way to reset it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [su postgres: Sorry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765269/su-postgres-sorry)

Comment: [The original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765269/su-postgres-sorry) of this duplicate was closed as off-topic. So [I posted the same Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221043/19079) with [a solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/221044/19079) on the DBA Stack Exchange sister site.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're trying to access the *system* user named `postgres`. According to comments you left on the  other answers, there is no such user. You can't change the password of a user that doesn't exist.

Perhaps it's `_postgres` or `postgres_`? I know some installers on OS X use weird names. Or perhaps your install never successfully created a `postgres` user on your system in the first place, so you can't set a password for it?

In general you *never need to set a password for this user*. You can just

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

or whatever command you need to run as the `postgres` superuser.

Note that [you shouldn't need `su`](https://serverfault.com/q/601140/102814) for anything.

Answer (score 39):

> I installed postgresql on mac using brew. I wasn't asked about for the
>   password for postgresql during the installation.

That's normal because `brew` doesn't need or create any `postgres` account.
The PostgreSQL processes run under your own account. The other 3 answers so far are wrong in this regard.

See the output of `brew info postgres` for information.

To create a new database account, you may launch, from your own OS account:

`/usr/local/bin/createdb someusername`

or within psql:

`/usr/local/bin/psql -d postgres`

and then as an SQL command: `CREATE USER someusername PASSWORD 'somepassword';`

This should work because brew has normally created at `initdb` time:

- a database superuser account with the same login as your OS account (seems to be `alex` in your case)
- a database named `postgres` that may be used to log info for administrative tasks such as creating a user.

The point of using the full path `/usr/local/bin` is to reach the commands provided by `brew`, as opposed to the commands with the same name that come with the system and are located in `/usr/bin` or the commands with the same name that are potentially installed by other PostgreSQL providers, such as postgres.app or macports or entreprisedb. There are 5-6 competing and incompatible ways of getting postgresql installed on Mac OS X.

EDIT: the newer versions of MacOS X desktop edition no longer have the postgres client-side commands pre-installed. This seems to be the case at least since MacOS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and possibly 10.9.

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer. Brew's installation doesn't have a `postgres` user.

Comment: Is there any way to password protect this system level user? When I run `psql postgres` and then `\password` it has no effect.

Comment: @bryankennedy: most probably this is due to [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) using `peer` or `trust` locally. Replace these with `md5`.

Answer (score 7):

There is no default password. To run a shell as user `postgres` use ([as advised by Craig](https://serverfault.com/q/601140/102814)):

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

Type `exit` when done. See:

- [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist/11919677#11919677)

Turns out, the user wasn't created at all. Look to [@Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23995110/939860).

Comment: actually it says "su: unknown login: postgres"

Comment: Why does everyone use `sudo su - postgres`? `sudo` supports user-impersonation directly, and without the horrible quoting mess you land up with `su`. Just `sudo -u postgres psql` or whatever.

Comment: @CraigRinger: If I plan do do a couple of things as the `postgres` user, it's much more convenient to switch to the role and `exit` when done. And what "quoting mess"?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter For a login shell use `sudo -u postgres -i`. As for quoting: `su` passes its argument to `$SHELL -c`. So you'll have undesired results from (say) `sudo su - postgres -c psql -c "SELECT 1;"`, wheras `sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT 1;"` works correctly. To do the equivalent with `su` requires another layer of quoting to protect the argument, like `sudo su - postgres -c "psql -c \"select 1\"";`. Using `su` as well as `sudo` is just redundant. Finally, if you have a `sudoers` that lets you become `postgres` but not `root`, it just won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something. I was using `sudo su` out of habbit. `sudo -u postgres -i` seems like the better alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Why not:

```
sudo passwd postgres
```

This will prompt you for the password of your current account. Then it will ask you to enter the new password (twice) for the `postgres` user.

Comment: actually it says "su: unknown login: postgres"

Answer (score 0):

I'm Nura, after I installed postgresql with homebrew on macOS Catalina MBP 13 inch Mid 2012,i do got the same error as Mr. Incerteza. I SOLVED it with different ways, when I got the error, I ran

1. brew services start postgresql@14
2. /usr/local/bin/psql -d postgres

Then the terminal database has open.