# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed

Tags: postgresql

When ever I am trying to run psql in the command line, it is asking for a `Password:` .

I'm not too sure what the username and password is.

I installed postgresql by `brew install postgres`

pg_hba.conf

```
# the database superuser.  If you do not trust all your local users,
# use another authentication method.


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     AustinTruong                                trust
#host    replication     AustinTruong        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     AustinTruong        ::1/128                 trust
```

Let me know if there is any confusion in my question.

### Edit

[image]

In other posts, it mentions if I change pg_hba.conf file to `local all all trust`, I shouldn't require a password. But it is still requesting for a password.

When I run `brew info postgres` [image]

I've followed the steps from [Postgresql: password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres), but i'm still having the same issue. I added the line

`local   all              postgres                              ident`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a new database account from you own OS account use:

```
/usr/local/bin/createdb someusername
```

See if this works.
[Also this other SO Question might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23995110/3103677)

Edit:

Use `brew info postgres` for more information about your version.

Comment: Hmm.. When I run that commend it is still requesting for a password. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am still getting the same issue. It seems like when I use my normal sudo password it still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you get when you run: brew info postgres

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as correct since it helped you, thanks.

Comment: I still haven't figured out the solution, I will mark it as the solution once it figure out. Thanks!

Comment: Oh haha okay, I thought you did. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: hello from 2017.. running into this exact issue :(